# Fouled up my openjdk-8-jre

Tags: uninstall, jdk, openjdk, purge

Ubuntu 16.04. I was trying to run pycharm, and realized that I must have corrupted my jre at some point. Even after doing:

```
sudo apt purge openjdk-8-jre
```

running `java -version` gives me:

```
nick@imipramine:~$ java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

How can I completely remove all Java jres and jdks from my system before re-installing? Or am I missing something super basic?

BTW, I tried:

```
apt purge openjdk-9-internal
apt purge openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jdk
```

And `openjdk-8-jdk`.

Some files were removed, but `java -version` still reports that openjdk is  installed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you did *not* build OpenJDK from source, this will uninstall any package starting with `openjdk`:

```
sudo apt remove --purge "^openjdk.*"
```

**Including any program depending on a Java runtime environment.**

Comment: Thank-you! That worked. I then did "sudo apt install default-jre" and PRESTO... pycharm is up and running.

Comment: @NickChackowsky If this solved your problem please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark to its left.  Putting SOLVED in the question title is not how it works here.